# match several occurrences or one occurence of specific char

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression that matches unlimited occurrences of any alphanumeric char or a single hyphen maximum
for example

`ab+c` should match

`ab++c` should not match

`abcd` should match

`abc+` should match

`+abcd` should match

can you help?

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't a code-writing service. Also, what about `a+b+c`?

Comment: [`^(?:(?!\+{2})[[:alnum:]+])+$`](https://regex101.com/r/QAfSCj/1)?

Comment: There's also this option: [`^\+?(?:[[:alnum:]]+\+?)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/QAfSCj/3). It uses less steps than my previous comment's regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Brief

There are a few options available depending on the usage and exact requirements as they are not all present in the original question.

**Note**: The word *hyphen* (or its plural form *hyphens*) shall henceforth refer to the `+` character (as per the OP's definition in the original question)

---

### Code

The below options allow for multiple *hyphens*, however, preventing two *hyphens* from repeating after one another.

#### Option 1

**~ 116 steps**

[See this regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/QAfSCj/1)

```
^(?:(?!\+{2})[[:alnum:]+])+$
```

This regex allows alphanumeric or `+` characters, but negates a match of two *hyphens* back-to-back.

#### Option 2

**~ 66 steps**

[See this regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/QAfSCj/3)

```
^\+?(?:[[:alnum:]]+\+?)+$
```

This regex allows an optional *hyphen* at the beginning, followed by one or more of the following group {one or more alphanumeric characters followed by a *hyphen*}

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using this regular expression
`[\w]*\+?[\w]*`

thank you!

Comment: `\w` doesn't need to be enclosed in `[]`. Also, `\w` will match underscore character `_`, thus, with your query, `_+_` is valid. Also, please see my comments below your question. Is the example `a+b+c` valid? If so, this won't match it.